# MySQL Enterprise Backup download site

Tags: mysqldump, mysql-5.7

I was given a sever to use for tests that has MySQL commercial version installed. I would like to test backups using MySQL MEB, but cannot find the download site. I have seen many blogs mentioning that I need a file

```
meb-3.12.3-linux-glibc2.5-x86-64bit.tar.gz
```

But cannot find a website where I can actually download the MEB file. Should MySQL Backup already come pre-packaged with the MySQL commercial version and just need to find the executable file? I am new to MySQL enterprise, but familiar with mysqldump and xtrabackup. Unfortunately, mysqldump is too slow, and xtrabackup does not work with MySQL Enterprise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unclear if the commercial version you mention is a trial or a purchased version of MySQL Enterprise. You should get Oracle credentials for download in the first case associated with your license.

In both cases, you have here a link to both the trial and licensed versions of MySQL Enterprise Edition (including Enterprise Backup):

https://www.mysql.com/trials/